# Issue with Apex Charts rendering twice with Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, apexcharts

I am using Apex Charts with Vue 3. When the chart renders (draws), its rendering twice. The weird thing is, the second chart is removed from the DOM as soon as I resize or move the browser window. I've also double checked my Vue components to make sure I am not importing this chart component twice.

```
<template>

<apexchart
  width="500"
  height="400"
  type="bar"
  :options="chartOptions"
  :series="series">
</apexchart>

</template>

<script>

import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";

export default {
    name: 'ChartExample',
    components: {
        apexchart: VueApexCharts
    },
    data() {
        return {
            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                    id: "vuechart-example",
                },
                xaxis: {
                    // categories loaded here
                },
            },
            series: [
                // data loaded here
            ],
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.series = [
            {
            name: 'precip',
            data: [1,2,3,4,5],
            }
        ];
        this.chartOptions.xaxis = {
            categories: [1,2,3,4,5],
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

I'm passing in the data in the mounted hook because I plan on passing in dynamic data. When I add static data directly in the chart options (i.e. not passed in from the mounted hook), the chart is rendered once and works correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

After doing some research I've found this is a known bug in apex charts with Vue3.

https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts/issues/3

The only solution that worked for me is this.

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    });
}
```

Comment: I can confirm your solution works. However, I had to import { nextTick } from 'vue' and call nextTick(() => { window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')) })

Answer (score 3):

Well the solution that is present above `nextTick()` it works but it's not feasible and it's a bad solution.
I have implemented a solution which is better than `nextTick()`.

Just add a key attribute ":key='Series.length'" to your component i.e

```
      `<chart
          width="100%"
          :options="GraphOptions"
          :series="Series.length > 0 ? Series : []"
          :key="Series.length" 
          @mounted="ChartLoaded = true"
        ></chart>`
```

Issue will be resolved

Comment: It's always good to use keys when updating components, however the ApexChart was still rendered twice. The nextTick solution was indeed the only one helping. Btw. why do you use <chart> when the user explicitely uses <apexchart..>?